# How to change the line spacing of the first line of text in a UITextView only when there's more than one line of text rendered?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, contentsize

I have a subclass of UITextView used to display a custom view within the text flow.  It's adding an exclusionPath for the custom view, and rendering it's content within that region using autolayout.  That part is working, and the text wraps around the image as well.  The challenge is that I want to have custom line spacing such that the second line of text is always below the image.  I've played with layoutManager:lineSpacingAfterGlyphAtIndex:withProposedLineFragmentRect: and can adjust the line spacing for characters using a row calculation based on the contentSize and lineHeight.

I can determine if a character is in the first line and adjust it's lineSpacing correctly.  The problem is when a character wraps, the first character won't cause a re-check of the characters on the first line.  If I type a second wrapped character then all is fine; the first line will have the line spacing added to it.  This causes the layout to jump when the second wrapped character is entered.

In other words what I'm trying to do:
- Put a custom UIView inside of a UITextView
- Have a standard line height for a single line of text.
- If more than 1 line of text is needed then adjust line 1's lineSpacing to wrap line 2 under the image.

Sorry if my diagram is crude, but here's what I'm seeing:

```
--------------  First line of text view content  
| CustomView |  second line of text view content  
--------------  third line of text view content
fourth line of text view content
```

Here's What I'd like:

```
--------------  First line of text view content  
| CustomView |  
-------------- 
second line of text view content
third line of text view content  
fourth line of text view content
```

Am I missing something?  Is the contentSize.height just not updated until after the character is rendered?  Is there a better way to get the height of the box, or determine if the textbox is rendering to more than one line?

**Update:** I can identify the case where the number of rows (based on contentSize) is 1 (should be 2) but the glyph's rect.origin.y is > 0, then call invalidateIntrinsicContentSize.  That does allow the rendering to display as it's needed, but does cause extra calls to invalidate and seems pretty heavy.

Comment: I did not understand the circumstances of the error: Why should the first line been rechecked? Maybe you add a screen shot or diagram.

Comment: I've edited it to have a diagram.  I want the first line's spacing to remain normal until it wraps, then I need to have it's spacing increased to push the second line under neat the CustomView.